# the second js file enqueued inside wp plugin isn't read

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

Inside a wordpress plugin : The second enqueued js file isn't read, need I specify something ?
Does registering is necessary when several js files are called (enqueued) ?

```
function atv_internationalization() {
    wp_enqueue_style('atv-translate-css', plugins_url('', ATVTRANSLATE) . '/atvinternationalization.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('atv-translate-js', plugins_url('', ATVTRANSLATE) . '/atvinternationalization.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('atv-converturl-js', plugins_url('', ATVTRANSLATE) . '/atv_permalink/replaceurl.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'atv_internationalization');
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'atv_internationalization');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'atv_internationalization');
```

`atvinternationalization.css`  and `atvinternationalization.js` work.

`replaceurl.js` is well included inside wp footer but the script isn't read or interpreted even just for console.log('something');
Each jQuery file is instantiated like this:

```js
console.log("something"); // works outside jQuery
jQuery.noConflict(); don't resolve problem : It's not a jQuery conflict 
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').text("something"); // doesn't read 
    });
});
```

I checked the good way to  directory file .

Must I use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead, if yes why ?
I emptied browser cache many times

Update :
This method doesn't solve the problem :

```
function atv_internationalization() {
    wp_enqueue_style('atv-translate-css', plugins_url('', ATVTRANSLATE) . '/atvinternationalization.css');
    wp_register_script( 'atv-converturl-js', plugins_url('', ATVTRANSLATE) . '/atv_permalink/replaceurl.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('atv-translate-js', plugins_url('', ATVTRANSLATE) . '/atvinternationalization.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('atv-converturl-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('atv-translate-js');
}
```

Comment: If the `<script>` tag is included in the HTML with the correct URL then it's been enqueued correctly. WordPress has done it's job. If the script isn't working then it's a problem with the script. If your script is the last thing on the page, then `(document).ready(` may have already run by the time your script is loaded, meaning that it won't run.

Comment: what does your browsers dev tools console say? 404? Are there errors? The JS you've included doesn't do anything, the `console.log` is commented out. This is extremely unlikely to be a WordPress problem if the script tag is in the HTML and points to the correct URL

Comment: @jacob-peattie : delete '(document).ready(' doesn't fixed the issue. No there are lot of wp script after .

Comment: @tom-j-nowell : console.log say nothing , no error. I update my question

Comment: @tom-j-nowell , I have this error 'Failed to load resource: Operation could not be completed (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)' but I don't think it concerns my problem .

Comment: A `console.log("it works");` or `alert("it works")` is all that's needed to test this, and it looks like it does based on your updated edits ( the `// it works` ). This confirms the problem has nothing to do with WordPress and that you have a general Javascript problem, not a WordPress problem. It's very very likely that the cause of your mistake is a very basic mistake and misunderstanding about how and why people use self calling functions aka `(function($){....});` is wrong. You should ask about this on stackoverflow

Comment: also note that the jQuery that comes with WP is already in no conflict mode

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved:
Thanks for your time and help.
Jquery must be called like that, It's a mistake from me.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
    });
})(jQuery);
```